# bijection map from set of all positive real numbers to the interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: functions

Let $S = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid 0 < x < 1 \}$.
Show that $\Bbb R^+ \sim S$.

**Attempt:**
Let $f:(1,\infty) \to (0,1)$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \in (1,\infty)$. Let $x,y \in (1,\infty)$ and assume that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then, by definition of $f$, $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y}$ i.e. $x=y$. Hence, $f$ is injective.
Now, for all $y \in (0,1)$, there exists
$x=\frac{1}{y} \in (1,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{y} \right) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}} = y$. Hence, $f$ is surjective. Thus, $f$ is bijective i.e. $(1,\infty) \sim (0,1)$.

Next, define $g : \Bbb R^+ \to (1,\infty)$ by $g(x) = x+1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^+$.
Let $x,y \in \Bbb R^+$ and assume that $g(x) = g(y)$. Then, by definition of $g$, $x+1=y+1$ i.e. $x=y$ and hence $g$ is injective. Now, for all $y \in (1,\infty)$, there exists $x= y-1 \in \Bbb R^+$ such that $f(x) = f( y-1 ) = (y-1)+1 = y$ and thus $g$ is surjective.

Hence, $g$ is bijective i.e. $\Bbb R^+ \sim (1,\infty)$.

Finally, define a mapping from $\Bbb R^+ \to (0,1)$ by compositioning $g$ on $f$ i.e. $f \circ g$. Then, $(f \circ g)(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^+$ is a bijection map from $\Bbb R^+$ to $(0,1)$ i.e. $\Bbb R^+ \sim (0,1)$.

Am I true?

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: @coffeemath Okay! Thanks sir!

Comment: You could prove this is on shot with a function like $$y=\tan\Big(\pi x - \frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$$ But if it ain't broke, don't fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Correct. (I can not write comment directly, not enough rep)

Comment: Okay bro! Thanks!